# How to get Python 3 to match '%'?

Tags: python-3.x, string-matching

I have a file with one line beginning as:

`%i,the,you,to,and,a,me,it,not,in,my,is`

In the code to read lines from the file, there is an if statement

```
if line[0] == '%':
    <do something>
```

However, even though the character is there, it never matches.

Anyone have any ideas what might be happening here?  Is this possibly an encoding issue?

Comment: how are you reading the file?

Comment: Try printing out line[0] and see what it does. For all we know, this should be working, so the problem is in something you are not telling us.

Comment: @AnthonySottile

Reading like this:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
    if line[0] == '%':
        <do something>
```

Comment: @Welsy, printing line[0] yields the %.

Comment: Try replacing the condition with if '%' in line[0], see if that works

Comment: @Welsy, That's a no go with that idea since the line might contain a percent character somewhere else.  I am specifically looking for the first character of a particular line to begin with %.